# How to use node.js on container that has a "WORKDIR /app" in its image to access a shared volume (volumes_from)?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-volume

I have 2 containers, the first ('client') writes files to a volume while the second ('server') needs to read them (this is a simplified version of my requirement). My problem is that I don't know how to access the files from the second container using node.js when it is set with a `WORKDIR /app`.

(I've seen examples of how to access volume using `volumes_from`, like this one: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers which works on my tests, but it doesn't demonstrate my settings)

this is my docker-compose file (simplified):

```
volumes:
  aca_storage:

services:
  server-test:
    image: aca-server:0.0.1
    container_name: aca-server-test
    command: sh -c "npm install && npm run start:dev"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes_from:
      - client-test:ro
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development

  client-test:
    image: aca-client:0.0.1
    container_name: aca-client-test
    ports:
      - 81:80
    volumes:
      - aca_storage:/app/files_to_share
```

This is the docker file for the aca-server image:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["./package*.json", "./"]
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
CMD [ "node", "main.js"]
```

on my server's node app I'm trying to read files like this:

```
    fs.readdir(PATH_TO_SHARED_VOLUME, function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
        }
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            console.log(file);
        });
    });
```

but all my tests to fill PATH_TO_SHARED_VOLUME with valid path failed. For example:

- /aca_storage
- /aca_storage/_data
- /acaproject_aca_storage
- /acaproject_aca_storage/_data

(acaproject is the VS Code workspace name which I noticed is being added automatically)

Using docker cli on the 'aca-server-test' container, I'm getting:

```
/app #
```

which with ls exposes only the files/folders on my node.js app but doesn't allow access to the volume 'aca_storage' as happens with the examples I can find on the internet.

If relevant, my environment is:

- Windows 10 Home with WSL2
- Docker Desktop set as Linux Containers

I'm noob with Linux and Docker so as many details as possible will be appreciated.

Comment: Just mount the volume into both containers.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the same storage into different containers on different paths.  I'd avoid using `volumes_from:`, which is inflexible and a little bit opaque.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  aca_storage:
services:
  client:
    volumes:
      - aca_storage:/app/data
  server:
    volumes:
      - aca_storage:/app/files_to_share
```

In each container the mount path needs to match what the application code is expecting, but they don't necessarily need to be the same path.  With this configuration, in the server code, you'd set `PATH_TO_SHARED_VOLUME = '/app/files_to_share'`, for example.

If VSCode is adding a bind mount to replace the server image's `/app` directory with your local development code, `volumes_from:` will also copy this mount into the client container.  That could result in odd behavior.

Sharing files between containers adds many complications; it makes it hard to scale the setup and to move it to a clustered setup like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes.  A simpler approach could be for the client container to HTTP POST the data to the server container, which can then manage its own (unshared) storage.

Comment: Thanks @david. It works for the simple case I've described (actually on my many iterations of trials and errors I tried a similar thing but apparently I missed something..) Anyway, putting aside your advices on why not using the ```volumes_from:```, technically, is it possible? If yes, can you share how?

Comment: The YAML fragment in my answer is @ChrisBecke's suggestion from comments, "mount the same volume into both containers".  If both images have their code in the same container-side path, and VSCode is injecting a bind-mount of the server code to that path, then you can't use `volumes_from:`.

Comment: what do you mean by"If both images have their code in the same container-side path, and VSCode is injecting a bind-mount of the server code to that path"? Seems on my intent to simplify the things, I made it unclear. Actually the client is not my code but a 3rd party container (and image) that saves files to a local (in the container) folder. That's also why I cannot use POST (per your initial suggestion). Why where VSCode injects the files has any relevance? Summarizing my question would be (I think) - how to make ```volumes_from:``` work when the container using it works in a defined folder?